# dfply.mutate does not work with pandas.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dfply

I have a DataFrame for which

`hub2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(hub2.timestamp)`

works, but when I write

`hub2 >> mutate(time=pd.to_datetime(X.timestamp))`

with https://github.com/kieferk/dfply
I get the error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 419, in to_datetime
    elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/types/generic.py", line 9, in _check
    return getattr(inst, attr, '_typ') in comp
TypeError: __nonzero__ should return bool or int, returned Call`

Why is that?

Comment: Yes, I think it is bug. https://github.com/kieferk/dfply/issues/27

Comment: @jezrael: I think so too, but I added the issue ;-). Then I thought, maybe it is not a bug and I better ask SO.

Comment: One thing, it is not typo only? And also try add `[]` - `hub2 >> mutate(time=pd.to_datetime(hub2['timestamp']))`

Comment: @jezrael: The `X.` is on purpose. If you look into dfply's documentation you will see that this is referring to the input dataframe.

Comment: Ok, so good luck!